# Library not installed with build make Android Studio but works with CMAKE-GUI

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake, build.gradle, android-build

System information:

> Android Studio 3.2.1
> Linux Ubuntu 16.04

### Introduction

---

I recently came across a problem with my IDE (Android Studio). I use it to develop a Native / Java Application alongside Gradle and CMakeLists.

I use a few CMakeLists to export some functions in C/C++ to use with my app.

So these Cmakelists will create some library that can be used.

### Problem

---

When I "make" my project it will build successfully, but the library doesn't change, whether it's modified, or not.

After that, I thought that I might need to "Clean my project" before doing it, but nothing good happened.

***You can see my build.gradle under the post.***

### Tried Solution

---

The workaround I found is to compile each library with CMAKE-GUI and then compile my Android project to see the modification previously made.

That's bad and not normal, I think.

### Help

---

I want to know why my project doesn't make again my library and "install" it in the appropriate folder.

It's unnecessary to show my CMakeLists because it works on CLion with Linux and Windows with Visual Studio.

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.media.[NAME_OF_MY_PROJET]"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-O3  -fno-stack-protector -fintegrated-as "

                arguments "-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                        "-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=24", "-DANDROID_NDK=/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Android/Sdk/"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
          /*  customDebugType {
                debuggable true
            } */
            debug {
                jniDebuggable true
            }
       /* release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }*/
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Please, provide content of your Gradle script **in the question post** itself, not just link to it. Among other reasons, it is a requirement of the Stack Overflow, see [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I agree with your recommendation and I added the content of my build.gradle in my post.

Comment: it come from any of these options passed. `-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=24` appears strange.

Comment: What do you mean with "appears strange" ? Because in this link : 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/cmake-utils/+/cmake-master-dev/android.toolchain.cmake  --> ctrl + F "ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL, it exist.  I don't understand why it's stange, could you say more about it ?